# Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {username})

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm starting to learn React and following the tutorial and got stuck with this error when I was trying to upload picture. When I press upload button, this error "Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {username}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead." shown up and I couldn't reload the page anymore.
[Render Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x9UcE.jpg)
Here are the codes:

1.App.js

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import './App.css';
import Post from './Post';
import { auth, db } from "./firebase";
import Modal from '@material-ui/core/Modal';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import { Button, Input } from "@material-ui/core";
import ImageUpload from './ImageUpload';

function getModalStyle() {
  const top = 50;
  const left = 50;

  return {
    top: `${top}%`,
    left: `${left}%`,
    transform: `translate(-${top}%, -${left}%)`,
  };
}

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  paper: {
    position: 'absolute',
    width: 400,
    backgroundColor: theme.palette.background.paper,
    border: '2px solid #000',
    boxShadow: theme.shadows[5],
    padding: theme.spacing(2, 4, 3),
  },
}));

function App() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [modalStyle] = React.useState(getModalStyle);
  const [posts, setPosts] = useState([]);
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
  const [openSignIn, setOpenSignIn] = useState('');
  const [username, setUsername] = useState('');
  const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
  const [user, setUser] = useState(null);
  //UseEffect -> Run a piece of code based on a specific condition

  useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = auth.onAuthStateChanged((authUser) => {
      if (authUser) {
        //user has logged in...
        console.log(authUser);
        setUser(authUser);
      } else {
        //user has logged out...
        setUser(null);
      }

      return () => {
        //perform some cleanup action
        unsubscribe();
      }
    })
  }, [user, username]);

  useEffect(() => {
    //this is where the code runs
    db.collection('posts').onSnapshot(snapshot => {
      //everytime a new post is added, this code fires...
      setPosts(snapshot.docs.map(doc => ({
        id: doc.id,
        post: doc.data()
      })));
    })
  }, []);

  const signUp = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    auth
      .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
      .then((authUser) => {
        return authUser.user.updateProfile({
          displayName: username
        })
      })
      .catch((error) => alert(error.message))
  }


  const signIn = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    auth
      .signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
      .catch((error) => alert(error.message))

    setOpenSignIn(false);
  }

  return (
    <div className="app">

      {user?.displayName ? (
        <ImageUpload username={user.displayName} />
      ) : (
          <h3>Sorry you need to login to upload</h3>
        )}


      <Modal
        open={open}
        onClose={() => setOpen(false)}
      >
        <div style={modalStyle} className={classes.paper}>
          <form className="app__signup">
            <center>
              <img
                className="app__headerImage"
                src="https://www.instagram.com/static/images/web/mobile_nav_type_logo.png/735145cfe0a4.png"
                alt=""
              />
            </center>
            <Input
              placeholder="username"
              type="text"
              value={username}
              onChange={(e) => setUsername(e.target.value)}
            />
            <Input
              placeholder="email"
              type="text"
              value={email}
              onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
            />
            <Input
              placeholder="password"
              type="password"
              value={password}
              onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}
            />
            <Button type="submit" onClick={signUp}>Sign Up</Button>
          </form>
        </div>
      </Modal>

      <Modal
        open={openSignIn}
        onClose={() => setOpenSignIn(false)}
      >
        <div style={modalStyle} className={classes.paper}>
          <form className="app__signup">
            <center>
              <img
                className="app__headerImage"
                src="https://www.instagram.com/static/images/web/mobile_nav_type_logo.png/735145cfe0a4.png"
                alt=""
              />
            </center>
            <Input
              placeholder="email"
              type="text"
              value={email}
              onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
            />
            <Input
              placeholder="password"
              type="password"
              value={password}
              onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}
            />
            <Button type="submit" onClick={signIn}>Sign In</Button>
          </form>
        </div>
      </Modal>

      <div className="app__header">
        <img
          className="app__headerImage"
          src="https://www.instagram.com/static/images/web/mobile_nav_type_logo.png/735145cfe0a4.png"
          alt="" />
      </div>
      {user ? (
        <Button onClick={() => auth.signOut()}>Logout</Button>
      ) : (
          <div className="app__loginContainer">
            {/* : is stand for OR */}
            <Button onClick={() => setOpenSignIn(true)}>Sign In</Button>
            <Button onClick={() => setOpen(true)}>Sign Up</Button>
          </div>

        )}

      <h1>Hello Joes! Let's build an Instagram CLone with React</h1>
      {
        posts.map(({ id, post }) => (
          <Post key={id} username={post.username} caption={post.caption} imgUrl={post.imgUrl} />
        ))
      }

    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Here is the ImageUpload file
2. ImageUpload.js

```js
import { Button } from '@material-ui/core'
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { storage, db } from './firebase';
import firebase from "firebase";

function ImageUpload(username) {

    const [image, setImage] = useState(null);
    const [progress, setProgress] = useState(0);
    const [caption, setCaption] = useState('');

    const handleChange = (e) => {
        if (e.target.files[0]) {
            setImage(e.target.files[0]);
        }
    };

    const handleUpload = () => {
        const uploadTask = storage.ref(`images/${image.name}`).put(image);
        uploadTask.on(
            "state_change",
            (snapshot) => {
                //progress funtion...
                const progress = Math.round(
                    (snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 100
                );
                setProgress(progress);
            },
            (error) => {
                //Error function...
                console.log(error);
                alert(error.message);
            },
            () => {
                // Complete function...
                storage
                    .ref("images")
                    .child(image.name)
                    .getDownloadURL()
                    .then(url => {
                        // Post image on db

                        db.collection("posts").add({
                            timestamp: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
                            caption: caption,
                            imageUrl: url,
                            username: username
                        });
                        setProgress(0);
                        setCaption("");
                        setImage(null);
                    });
            }
        );
    };


    return (
        <div>
            {/* I want to have... */}
            {/* Caption input */}
            {/* File picker */}
            {/* Post button */}
            <progress value={progress} max="100" />
            <input type="text" placeholder="Enter a caption..." onChange={event => setCaption(event.target.value)} value={caption} />
            <input type="file" onChange={handleChange} />
            <Button onClick={handleUpload}>
                Upload
        </Button>
        </div>
    )
}
export default ImageUpload
```

Thanks guys!

Comment: You've forgotten to post here the entire content of your `node_modules` dir

Comment: This question is too verbose (more than appropriate in this case). You should remove irrelevant code, to make it easier to read it, and more likely that somebody is willing to answer.

Answer (score 0):

This line is wrong:

```
<progress value={progress} max="100" />
```

1. React components have to be upper case.
2. Your `progress` is a number, not a React component

You probably wanted to import the component `Progress` and write:

```
<Progress value={progress} max="100" />
```